# How Do You Integrate Stripe Checkout Session With Laravel 8

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-8

I'm new to Stripe and Laravel, but I managed to get Stripe elements working without a problem.  The issue is, I need to pass some shipping rates to the customer via Stripe Checkout Session, because you can't do it through Stripe Elements.  In my StripeController, everything is set up for Stripe Elements, but how exactly do you setup Stripe Checkout in the Laravel 8 controller and the javascript which appears to use express js?

Here is my Stripe Controller as it is...

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('####');

// Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  'amount' => $total_amount*100,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'description' => '',
  'source' => $token,
  'metadata' => ['order_id' => uniqid()],
]);

// dd($charge);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are mixed things which can cause confustion on your question. I will try to clarify them out one by one

1. To pass Shipping Rates during Stripe Checkout Session, you would want to follow this [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/shipping#create-checkout-session), create a Shipping Rate before hand and pass its ID into the Session creation call
2. Your provided code is to create a Charge. To create a Checkout Session, you will need a completely different code. You can refer to the PHP code in above guide. Choose "PHP" as your language of choice. [image]
3. As you are already using Laravel and PHP in server, you won't need express.js. express.js is a backend (not frontend) framework based on Node.js.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I read your suggestion and the documentation.  Now, I can't even get the Stripe form to show up.  With Stripe Elements, you returned an empty div with the id, but how do you do the same thing with Stripe Checkout?  Do you have to pass a form with action?

Comment: \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('####');

 $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
   'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
   'line_items' => [[
     'price' => $total_amount*100,
     'quantity' => 1,
   ]],
   'mode' => 'payment',
   'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
   'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
 ]);

Comment: const stripe = require('stripe')('###);

const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  line_items: [{
    price: '{{$cartTotal}}',
    quantity: 1,
  }],
  mode: 'payment',
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success?session_id={12345',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
});

Comment: Checkout is different than Elements, that you don't create an empty HTML div and mount. You simply retrieve Checkout Session's url and redirect to it.

In your client, create a form with a submit button to one of your server endpoint. In server, you create a Checkout Session and instruct client to redirect to it

Please also take a look at this flow: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web#redirect-customers

Comment: Still no dice.  When I click the the button to take me to the Stripe Checkout page, it gives a 404 error.

Comment: What did you return in server? Did you perform a redirect to $session.url?

Comment: yes. A redirect to $session->url solved the problem!!  Thanks for your help